# powershell regex match and update variables in script

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to match and update variables in a script. The script has variables like the examples below. I need a regex code that will match all 4 of those patterns in the script.

variables to match & update in script [plus variations]:

```
export LINUXSERVERFQDN='devserver.mtch.dam.gtmcs.com'
#LINUXSERVERFQDN variations = 'jsgsyuytrsg0122.jam.wert.gt.com' 'dftmhuayul0152.ejya.kam.tc.com' 'epwdfvwmiup0987.WDH.mpc.ad.pq.com' 'waupppm0jdg04.ypp.mpr.ws.qq.com'
export IPADDRESS='13.165.14.337'
export SITECODE='AGG'
export DATACOLLECTIONDBPWD='datacollection-micro-service-db-password'
#DATACOLLECTIONDBPWD variations = 'decknet-adaptor-micro-service-db-password' 'packing-micro-service-db-password' 'legacy-service-db-password' 'proficiency-service-db-password' 'traceability-service-db-password'
```

code:

```
$variables = @(
        @{ name = "LINUXSERVERFQDN"; value = 'wbghdks1234.ppcmr.naq.gcc.com'; },
        @{ name = "IPADDRESS"; value = '10.353.76.111'; },
        @{ name = "SITECODE"; value = 'GGG'; },
        @{ name = "DATACOLLECTIONDBPWD"; value = 'hkjsiudsudiusd8sd8ui'; }
    )

    foreach ($variable in $variables)
    {

        (Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw) -replace "$($variable.name)=(?-i)^[A-Z.]$", "$($variable.name)='$($variable.value)'" | Set-Content -Path $filePath
    }
```

Comment: Try `"$($variable.name)='.*'"`. Your regex contains `^` in the middle of the pattern, so it does not match any string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank but that doesn't match all 4 variables

Comment: [It works](https://regex101.com/r/JaVQah/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry I updated the question to include other variations. thank you.

Comment: Then try `"$($variable.name)\s*=\s*'[^']*'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I suggest replacing your regex (which doesn't quite work the way you want) with the following, which also simplifies the replacement operand:

  - `"(?m)(?<=^\s*export $($variable.name)=').*(?=')"`
  - Note:

    - I'm assuming that replacements should only be performed on (not commented-out)  `export ...` lines.
    - `-creplace`, the case-*sensitive* variant of the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is used below, obviating the need for `(?-i)`
    - Look-around assertions (`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`) are used to make the regex only capture the variable *value* to replace while asserting the presence of surrounding strings.
    - See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/R9hv2O/1) for an explanation of the regex and the ability to interact with it.
- Additionally, for better performance, I suggest performing all replacements *in memory* first, before writing the result back to the input file.

```bash
$variables = @(
        @{ name = "LINUXSERVERFQDN"; value = 'wbghdks1234.ppcmr.naq.gcc.com'; },
        @{ name = "IPADDRESS"; value = '10.353.76.111'; },
        @{ name = "SITECODE"; value = 'GGG'; },
        @{ name = "DATACOLLECTIONDBPWD"; value = 'hkjsiudsudiusd8sd8ui'; }
    )

$fileContent = Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $filePath
foreach ($var in $variables) {
  $fileContent = 
    $fileContent -creplace "(?m)(?<=^\s*export $($var.name)=').*(?=')", $var.value
}

# Note: To be safe, "out.txt" is used as the output file.
#       Once you're sure the code works as intended, you can
#       replace it with $filePath to update the input file in place.
Set-Content -NoNewline -LiteralPath out.txt -Value $fileContent
```